# VSTO Outlook: How to change email addresses in "To" field from compose window and avoid then to be applied to the rest of windows

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

In the compose window and under some conditions I need to mark some email addresses in the "To" field with an asterisk at the beginning. The problem of doing so is that then I need to manage many use cases in which I need to remove the asterisk before (for example, before sending).

Now I have seen that if you hold on the mouse over an email address in the "To" field, then a window is displayed offering you the possibility to add that email to your contacts. My problem is with this window in which the email address is displayed with the asterisk symbol at the beginning (see screenshot attached). So is there any way to remove the asterisk from that email address before it is shown in that window (but maintaining the asterisk in the "To" field in the compose window)?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible. The Outlook extensibility model doesn't provide anything for that. The best what you could do is to add a corresponding contact to the Address Book (Contacts) and then replace recipients dynamically when the item is going to be sent out. For example, you could handle the `ItemSend` event handler for that.

Comment: before showing that popup window, is there any event from that window i can subscribe to before showing it and just at that moment change that email address?

Comment: There is no specific even for the popup window. Try using the `PropertyChange` event.

Comment: PropertyChange event? and what property name should i handle there? I would like to show foo@foo.com instead of *foo@foo.com in that popup window. From where that popup window gets that email address? from the Outlook.MailItem.To field or from Outlook.MailItem.recipients?

Comment: As I wrote in my post, the Outlook extensibility model doesn't provide anything for that.  You may try using the `PropertyChange` event to replace a recipient because the popup windows gets information from your Address book, so you need to have a corresponding entry there.

Comment: But the problem is that I need to mark some recipients with the asterisk symbol (I got this) but now I don't want the email address to be shown in the popup window with that symbol at the beginning. I am wondering if there is a way to access the fields in the popup window once that popup window is opened. How that pop window is named? there is no possibility to change the value for its fields? sure?

Comment: There is no trivial way to customize the popups.

Comment: Ok, there is no trivial way, but then there is a way so Could you please tell me how? how can I access and modify the value of those fields in that popup window? I only want to change the fields containing the email address.